# Save jsonb data into Postgres from Java

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, orm

I have my json column in the database as a jsonb object and my ORM mapping has the following

```
@Column(name = "response_json")
@ColumnTransformer(write = "?::jsonb")
private String responseJson;
```

When I am trying to write to the database using saveOrUpdate()

```
myDao.updateJsonByTxId(i, myJson.toString());
```

I am converting myJson which is a JSONObject to a string and I get the following error

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "response_json" is of type jsonb but 
expression is of type character varying
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
Position: 48
```

The Json string is definitely a valid json, not sure what the issue is

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the `@ColumnTransformer` for this purpose. It is error prone solution.

1. You can write your own [hibernate type](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-custom-type). See for example this [article](https://thorben-janssen.com/persist-postgresqls-jsonb-data-type-hibernate/).
2. You can use for example [hibernate-types](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types) library. See this [article](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-objects-using-generic-hibernate-types/).